# Deleted primary partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I dual booted my laptop to run both linux and window. Yesterday, I tried to remove the linux partition of which i did successfully. Unfortunately the linux partition was the primary partition (yes I know this was dumb).

Problem:

The laptop will not boot at all because it's looking for the primary partition (linux).

What I tried:

Grub loads, two files are displayed and when I try to 'ls' each file, it says unknown file system.

My question:

How can i recover and boot into Windows 10? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try one of the following:

- boot from a linux live cd and reinstall grub with different configuration, pointing to Windows partition,
- alternatively, boot from a linux live cd and use testdisk to recover the partition (see https://www.maketecheasier.com/recover-data-and-partitions-for-free-with-testdisk/ for instructions),